# MySQL indexes eq to Key?

Tags: mysql, key, indexing

I would like to know if:

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_student ON Enrollment (student)
```

is equal to this:

```
KEY `IDX_student` (`student`)
```

It's related to mysql indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  MySQL treats INDEX and KEY as synonyms in most contexts.  They refer to the same data structure.

You can even declare an index in a CREATE TABLE using either KEY or INDEX:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
 x INT,
 y INT,
 KEY (x),
 INDEX (y)
);
```

---

Re your comment:

InnoDB in MySQL 5.5 and later (or 5.1 if you [enable the InnoDB plugin](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replacing-builtin-innodb.html)) supports [**Fast Index Creation**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb-plugin/1.0/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html), which builds only the index you create, and leaves the table and other existing indexes alone.

You don't need to do anything differently to take advantage of this feature, just `CREATE INDEX` or `ALTER TABLE...ADD KEY` as you would normally.  But fast index creation doesn't apply for the following cases:

- When changing a primary key.
- If you use MyISAM tables.
- If you use MySQL 5.0 or earlier
- If you use MySQL 5.1 and the "builtin" InnoDB

Comment: One more question, If I were add key to existing huge database will it build index for all rows which already exist or only for new ?